# Retrofit 2.0 response failed and return null for throwback if used Realm object encapsulation

Tags: android, retrofit, realm

Hi I'm new to Retrofit and Realm for Android so please bear with me if there is any silly code.

So I have a simple API in this case for login and this is the User object in my code :

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

@SerializedName("id")
private String ID;

@SerializedName("username")
private String username;

@SerializedName("token_type")
private String tokenType;

@SerializedName("token")
private String token;


//Setter and Getter goes here
}
```

The login API interface :

```
public interface LoginAPI {

@POST("api/v1/login")
Call<User> login(@Body JsonObject user);

}
```

And this is the implementation for request to my login API :

```
//OnClickListener
View.OnClickListener loginButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("username", emailEditText.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.addProperty("password", passwordEditText.getText().toString());

        Retrofit loginRequest = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        LoginAPI loginAPI = loginRequest.create(LoginAPI.class);

        Call<User> call = loginAPI.login(jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(LoginFragment.this);
    }
};



//API Callback
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    User user = response.body();

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed " + t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The problem is it always call onFailure callback and it returning NULL for Throwable t value.

My code is work when my User object is not extending the RealmObject but that mean I must create 2 object for Retrofit and Realm.

Is there any way for me to use 1 Object for both Retrofit and Realm implementation or is there any mistake or miss in my code?.
Much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with @Christian mention of using GSON and with this link [here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/121)
, finally I got this working with `@Expose`.

This is what in my code right now :

User object

```
public class User extends RealmObject {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String ID;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    private String tokenType;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("token")
    private String token;

   //Setter and Getter goes here
}
```

Login API interface :

```
public interface LoginAPI {
    @POST("api/v1/login")
    Call<JsonObject> login(@Body JsonObject user);
}
```

API callback for my Login API :

```
//API Callback
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    JsonObject results = response.body();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
    realm.beginTransaction();
    User user = gson.fromJson(results.toString(), User.class);
    realm.copyToRealm(user);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

And its work like a charm now. Hope this will help anyone that have a trouble to integrate Retrofit and Realm in their code!.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure GSON like described here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#retrofit

I am not that familiar with Retrofit 2 though, and it looks like the API has changed slightly, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes I tried with GSON initialization like you mention but it's ignoring the `@SerializedName` on my User object. Is there any way to GSON to running the `@SerializedName`?. Real thanks